# My .gitconfig file is in my Emacs home folder. How to prevent that?

Tags: git, emacs

I want it in `C:\Users\<username>\.gitconfig` where my other dot files are. But it seems to be paying attention to the Emacs $HOME env var. I google and see how to find where `.gitconfig` is stored, but I don't see how to set where it's stored.

Comment: Somebody voted to close this as "about general computing" but questions about git fall under "tools for programmers" and I feel this is on-topic for that reason.

Answer (score 1):

For years, I've just used $HOME for emacs. But I guess for years I've not really been using that envar properly. I set it to `c:\users\<username>` and moved my `.emacs.d` folder there. I think that's the right solution

Comment: Indeed, `$HOME` is in no way specific to Emacs. On Unix, it is set to your home directory automatically by the system. On Windows, Unix-compatible tools will generally expect you to do this manually.